# Converting OpenGL ES Code to OpenGL (on Mac)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, opengl, opengl-es

I need to convert some OpenGL ES code to OpenGL on Mac.
I already converted much of the code but I wondering what is the best way to convert:

```
[self.context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking about is how to set up a rendering target for displaying your OpenGL content in a view or layer. This is a little trickier than swapping out one method for another.

On iOS, you have CAEAGLLayer, which you use for backing any UIView that will display OpenGL ES content. The above method is attaching your render buffer to that.

On the Mac, you have either NSOpenGLView or CAOpenGLLayer (NSOpenGLLayer). These two are very different from each other, and both also differ from CAEAGLLayer. In the case of the Mac classes, you'll need to subclass one or the other and override the methods needed to set up your OpenGL context and render your content to the screen. In my experience, I've had difficulty getting CAOpenGLLayer to render content on a non-main thread, but it's a lot easier to overlay views and other layers on top of that than with NSOpenGLView.

You're most likely going to want to work from a template to set up your subclasses. Apple's [GLEssentials sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/GLEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010104) provides a good example of how to set up an NSOpenGLView, and their [CALayerEssentials](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CALayerEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008029) has code for a CAOpenGLLayer subclass.